# Timed fadeout on jQuery contact form

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using some jQuery I found on [this site](https://spruce.it/noise/simple-ajax-contact-form/) to make a contact form. The part I'm having trouble with is that when I submit a message that as an error, it shows up an error message. Then when I fix it, it shows a success message as well as the error message. Here's the code I'm using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $('.name-field').val();
        var email = $('.email-field').val();
        var text = $('.message-field').val();
        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&text=' + text;
        function isValidEmail(emailAddress){
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        };

        if (isValidEmail(email) && (text.length > 1) && (name.length > 1)){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'contact-form.php',
                data: dataString,
                success: function(){
                    $('.result-success').fadeIn(1000);
                }
                });
        }

        else{
            $('.result-error').fadeIn(1000);
        }

        return false;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact .name-field').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=24px');
    $('#contact .email-field').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=24px');
    $('#contact .message-field').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=24px');
});
```

I am thinking that the most efficient way of fixing this is to add a delayed fadeout of the success / error messages. Can someone tell me how I can do this?

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6McC3/)

Comment: can you provide fiddle for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. You can delay the message fadeout like this :

```
$('.result-success').fadeIn(1000);
//FadeOut after 2 seconds
setTimeout(function(){$('.result-success').fadeOut(1000);},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not hidding the error.
You could do:

```
 $('.result-error').fadeOut(1000);
```

inside the success function on the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if (isValidEmail(email) && (text.length > 1) && (name.length > 1)){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'contact-form.php',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){                    
                $('.result-success').delay(10000).fadeIn('slow');
                $('.result-error').hide();
            }
            });
    }

    else{
        $('.result-error').delay(10000).fadeIn('slow');
    }
```

Comment: Could work if you do ´$('.result-success').fadeIn('slow').delay(10000).fadeOut('slow');´ But I don't remember if the ´delay´ is a blocking function